# Highlight Multiple Elements at once in the Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When you mouse over an element in Elements tab of the Chrome console, it highlights the element in the viewport. Is there anyway to highlight multiple elements at once?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible using DevTools only. It might be possible using remote debugging protocol. But, what are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: I mainly just want to be able to visually confirm that some elements, that have whitespace at their edges, are lining up exactly how they're supposed to.

Comment: Then you probably want to use one of these extensions: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rulers?_category=extensions

Comment: I often find myself wanting to inspect two elements side-by-side, to see why the CSS differs. (I've inherited a dog's breakfast of CSS, and I haven't yet convinced the client it would be cheaper for them if they let me blow the whole thing up and start all over again.)

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852886/how-do-i-highlight-elements-in-chrome-dev-tools-after-ive-moved-my-mouse-away