# Chrome box model highlight multiple elements simultaneously

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to demo a layout technique to fellow developers and would like to have the box model highlighter active for a select number of elements at once.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Chrome extensions are suitable suggestions.

Comment: A quite similar question, also currently with no answer, unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175844/highlight-multiple-elements-at-once-in-the-chrome-console