# How do I Highlight Elements in Chrome Dev tools (after I've moved my mouse away)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Firefox dev tools, in the Rules tab that holds the CSS values, there's a super-useful little box you can click and it highlights the element on the page.

Is there a version of this in Chrome? I can't seem to see it anywhere.

Image attached from a screenshot in Firefox to show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: If I've understood correctly, what you need is the list of elements (highlighted on the page) that share the same class, right? Well in this case you just need to click on the definition of the class or Id.

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with a list of elements that's just coincidental to the screenshot.  I want it so I can select a particular element or matched elements and have them highlighted on the screen. There is a tool in the far left of the Chrome dev tools that allows you to select an element with your mouse but the highlight over the element disappears when you move your mouse away. Clicking on the definition of the class or Id doesn't do what the box in the FireFox screenshot does.

Comment: Simply hover the rule selector text.

Comment: But @wOxxOm I want i so it's highlighted highlighted after I move my mouse away, and unless they've changed the rules of the internet, hover is not possible when you move your mouse away.

Comment: It's possible to hold `Ctrl` key (on Windows) while hovering the selector text, but it may take a few attempts to make it stick, I haven't figured the exact sequence.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175844/highlight-multiple-elements-at-once-in-the-chrome-console